# Making a wordpress page the index on the site?

Tags: pages, homepage

Is it possible to make a "page, not a blog post" the main entry on your site?

I'd like to be able to create a summary of the latest content as the first page the user visits on my site.

I'm using Wordpress 3.0.3

Comment: yes, see settings > reading

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba Yup it was in there!  Thanks.  Now why don't you post that as a real answer so I can give you the credit for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's a simple setup in your wordpress settings,

so, go to your Admin area => Settings => Reading
and select to use a Static Page as a Front Page,
from the drop down menu select the page you want to use and put inside the content you want/need, just don't put a Loop inside.

Comment: **NOTE:** When setting either the front or posts page option, the other should also be set. When using these two options simply ensure you have two pages you can designate to them. If you set a front page for example, then you won't have a regular posts overview(ie. a base page that lists all posts), so remember to designate a posts page to.

Comment: You are correct @t31os, i totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a template file called "home.php"
But I also prefer the method with the wordpress settings.
It really depends on if the page looks different to a normal page.